# Error code '80004005' when using classic asp to connect accdb file

Tags: database, ms-access, asp-classic, database-connection

I've been trying for quite a while now to connect an .accdb file to a HTML file using classic-asp. Below is the code ive got so far to make the bridge to this connection which is not working.

```
<%@Language=VBScript %>
<%
Dim adoCon
Dim rsLogbook
Dim strSQL
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCon.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("DatabaseName.accdb")
Set rsLogbook = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT TableName.FieldName FROM TableName;"
rsLogbook.Open strSQL, adoCon
Response.Write ("<br>")
Response.Write (rsLogbook("FieldName"))
rsLogbook.Close
Set rsLogbook = Nothing
Set adoCon = Nothing
%>
```

The link worked perfectly when i was using an .mdb file but i cannot do that since i need some extra features that are only supported by .accdb file.

Below is the error code that i an getting

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Ive tried googling the error code and help with it but all im getting is IIS fixes which i do not need since im uploading this to a hosting website to test it out.

Note: I can use classic-asp and not asp.net :)

Comment: You could try the following *adoCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= & Server.MapPath("DatabaseName.accdb")"* (Can't test though)

Comment: Is the database file in the same folder as this asp script?

Comment: yes it is in the same folder